Why does my mesh look like this?

Why does my mesh look like this? I don't know
http://naver.me/5Tin2J8a

Hello, what bothers you exactly? Could you please share the object? https://blend-exchange.com/

ok http://naver.me/5Tin2J8a <-this is my file

your mesh is a mess with flipped normals, overlapping vertices and faces, etc, you need to model a clean mesh

thank you very much I'll give it a try

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

@moonboots That appears to be an answer. Please post it as such.

Thank you all for the answer Now I can focus on my dirty mesh

Your mesh is a mess with flipped normals, overlapping vertices and faces, etc, you need to model a clean mesh.
